# Zero-width histogram bin?

Tags: data-analysis

I want to plot a histogram of some timing data. The timing data, represented by a continuous variable t, is binned as follows:

```
t=0
0<t<=1
1<t<=2
2<t<=3
3<t<=4
```

I have frequency data for each bin. To plot this as a histogram, I understand that I ought to use frequency density; that is, the frequency divided by the bin width. But my first bin has zero width! How can one cope with this?

Comment: Why can't the first bin include $t = 0$?

Comment: @K.Miller $t$ represents some sort of delay. I'm particularly interested in showing explicitly the situations where there is no delay whatsoever.

Comment: You could add a bin $[-1,0]$ with the understanding that since $t \geq 0$, it corrsponds to observations at $t = 0$.

Comment: @K.Miller Mm I thought of that too and it's quite tempting. Still feels like a bit of a hack though!

Comment: I find it curious that you can detect a delay of exactly zero. How do you know when it occurs? What does it even mean?

Comment: @DavidK It's certainly a good question! It's because the data is obtained analytically rather than experimentally.

Comment: If the data are all integers then set the bins to $(n-\frac12,n+\frac12]$ for integers $n$. If the other data really are spread randomly within each of the intervals $(0,1], (1,2], \ldots$, it sounds like a model of a mixed probability distribution (or something that works like such a distribution), in which case maybe a cumulative distribution function would be a better representation. Or hack the histogram as already suggested; histograms aren't really designed to do mixed distributions.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks. The data is indeed real-valued within those intervals. I will look into a cumulative version. Feel free to upgrade your comment to an answer that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data that are analytically derived,
where some positive percentage of the data occur at a single exact value
and others may be found throughout some interval(s) on the real line,
a cumulative distribution function (CDF) is one way to clearly graph the data.

If this actually is a probability distribution of a random variable $X$, 
the CDF is given by $F(t) = P(X \leq t)$.
For the situation described in the question, where only values $t \geq 0$
can occur, you would have $F(t) = 0$ for all $t < 0$, then
$F(t) = P_0$ for $t = 0$, where $P_0$ is the fraction of data that
fall at $t = 0$ exactly, and $F(t)$ is increasing
for all $t > 0$ where the probability density at $t$ is positive,
$F(t)$ constant anywhere else.

This also works for data that are not random but that *act* like a
probability distribution, 
in this example a certain percentage at one exact value,
a certain percentage distributed in the interval $(0,1]$,
a certain percentage in the interval $(1,2]$, and so forth.
If all you had available (or all you wanted to determine) was the
frequencies for each of these bins and for the value $t=0$,
you could interpolate a straight line segment from
$(0,P_0)$ to $(1,P_0 + P_1)$ where $P_1$ was the fraction of data
falling in the interval $(0,1]$.